# Cannot capture the file already opened error in qt 5

Tags: c++, qt

I have this function which does an initial file check and returns false in case there is some error in opening the file.

```
FileHandler::FileHandler(QString str)   //getting the filename
:QFile(str){}

bool FileHandler::initialFileCheck()
{
    if(!fileHandler->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        globalVar::errorMessage = fileHandler->errorString();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

`fileHandler->errorString()` gives "unknown error" but over the console (Application output) I can see the error displayed that -- QFile::open: File (/home/test.txt) already open

How can I capture this error and put in my errorMessage?

I know I can use `fileHandler->error()` to get the error enumerator and then map a string to that enumerator but that is too much of useless creation of a map.

Any comment or suggestion is welcomed

Comment: The function that should be probably called isOpen should not open the file and then keep it open. If you want to check on file open, maybe it makes sense to do with actual QFile::open call and if it was already open then to handle an error and if it was not open but now open then there is no error. Generally in programming functions that check on something should not change anything, like do open the file -- changing the state of file.

Comment: I am sorry to miss it out, actually FileHandler inherits QFile so it is opening by QFile::open(). But you see the application output console displays the correct message. Seems like I have no option but either to check with isOpen() or map error Enums with string of comments